# XSD/XML RegEx Pattern Value

Tags: xml, regex, xsd

I have been provided with an XSD I am validating XML against.  The XML is failing validation because the XSD is incorrect. I have one field that is meant to allow a 1 - 3 character string. The first character has got to be A, B, C or Z and may optionally be followed by upto 2 characters.  I have not had much to do with regular expessions but have tried all manner of combinations to no avail.

The expression supplied is `<xs:pattern value="([A,B,C,Z]{1}\w\?{2})"/>`

Valid Examples of data are:

`B`
`B6`
`BB`
`AB`

Invalid:

`G3`
`A B`
`6HC`

Im sure its a fairly simple expression but I dont seen to be able to get it right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[ABCZ]\w{0,2}
```

No commas in `[]`. `{0,2}` allows for 0 to 2 word characters. Got rid of the `\?`, that would match a literal question mark.

Comment: Thanks John, I did have this and it is nearly there but it passes `A 4` as valid. The space between A and 4 needs to make it invalid.

Comment: Sorry John, I have been checking the expressions on an online RegEx checker seems Im either reading the results wrong or the checker is passing invalid data.  I updated the XSD and rechecked the XML.  Worked perfectly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is a kind of the regular expression. Each symbol have its meaning, I think all are trivial to understand except "?", which means the set of character that succeeds with ? have zero or one occurrence (Don't confuse with the * it means zero or many occurrence).
http://www.xmlschemareference.com/regularExpression.html